# Obtain the "one" side of the OneToMany relationship without repeated records in a custom Manager

Tags: django

I'm trying to retrieve the `one` side of the `OnetoMany` relationship, but this operation is conditioned by some criteria that must be met by the `many` side:

### Example

```py
# one side
class Car(models.Model):

# many side
class Obligation(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(to=Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    expiration_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
```

What I am looking for is to obtain all those `Car` with `Obligation` whose `expiration_date` are expired, for the following I have created a `manager` to perform this operation:

```py
from datetime import date

TODAY = date.today()


class CarManager(models.Manager):
    """Define a manager for Car model."""

    def with_obligations_expired(self) -> "QuerySet[Car]":
        """Get those cars whose obligations are expired."""
        return self.get_queryset().filter(
            obligation__expiration_date=TODAY
        )
```

### The problem

If one `Car` has 2 or 3 `Obligation` when you run `Car.objects.with_obligations_expired()` you will obtain:

`<QuerySet [<Car: car1>, <Car: car1>, <Car: car1>]>`

The result is a Queryset list with repeated records of cars because many obligations belong to one car then each obligation returns the car that belongs. but I need a list without repeated records.

I mean I need to get a list of those cars with expired obligations without repeated records.

Comment: You can add `distinct()` to the query to get distinct/unique results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to return the same object once:

```
from datetime import date

class CarManager(models.Manager):
    """Define a manager for Car model."""

    def with_obligations_expired(self) -> "QuerySet[Car]":
        """Get those cars whose obligations are expired."""
        return self.get_queryset().filter(
            obligation__expiration_date__lte=date.today()
        ).distinct()
```

This queryset will thus return a `Car` given there is *at least* one `Obligation` that is expired.

You might want to use the [**`__lt`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lt) or [**`__lte`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lte) to filter such that the expiration date is *before* today.

Comment: @OP: The removal of the `TODAY` variable and adding `date.today()` to the query is important. If your app ran for more than a day then the `TODAY` variable would be yesterday's date and would be incorrect

Comment: @IainShelvington what about if I want to get those cars whose obligations are going to expire then I want to get those oblations a day earlier something like `obligation__expiration_date__range=[YESTERDAY, TODAY]` where `TODAY = date.today()` and `YESTERDAY = TODAY - timedelta(days=1) ` in this situation I'm getting twice yesterday?

Comment: @CristianCamiloFlórez you would need to calculate `today` and `yesterday` when the method is called as these values are not static if your program runs long enough

Comment: @IainShelvington but if I need to create several methods in the Manager where I will need today or yesterday I would need to pass those dates in each of the functions as you suggest in the comment? Something like `obligation__expiration_date__range=[date.today() - timedelta(days=1),date.today()]` over and over again for all the methods they need yesterday and today?

Comment: @CristianCamiloFlórez: no, what Iain says it that you can not use a constant outside the class, that you need to calculate these in the method, so `date.today()` for example. If you define these as constants, eventually the server will continue running when the next day starts, and then the `TODAY` is not updated to that new day.

Comment: You could create a utility function named `yesterday` if you want to reduce the amount of code you write... `def yesterday(): return date.today() - timedelta(days=1)` and then call this function in place of where you were previously calculating it `range=[yesterday(), date.today()]`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what would be the best option as class attributes or as method variables? if I need to reuse them along different methods I would think that the best location would be as class attributes, because otherwise I would have to define them as variables in each method.

Comment: @IainShelvington The same for today? another utility function to avoid duplicated code? would be functions that I would use over different Manager...

Comment: Yes, you can do that if you think it will make your code clearer. You've mentioned creating lots of Manager methods - not every query needs to be a manager method and over using them will make your code harder to read as the reader will constantly have to refer back to the manager to find out what the query is doing